# Data protection API suddenly very slow

Tags: c#, performance, cryptography, dpapi

Our application is using the [Data Protection API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx) (via the [`ProtectedData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) class) to encrypt a password before storing it. It was working fine until recenly, but suddenly the `Protect` method started taking 2 seconds to return (instead of about 0.5ms). Things to note:

- it still works normally on my colleagues' machines
- we're using `DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser`; if I switch to `DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine`, it works normally again (but that's not what I want)
- I tried to restart the crypto service, which had no effect
- I tried to restart the computer, which had no effect either

What could be causing this? How can I fix it (preferably without reinstalling Windows)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappeared after I changed my account password.